# VsCode Python giving script error when terminal is created

Tags: python, installation

Im trying to set up python on visual stuidos code on my laptop. Im following the below guide, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Im stuck on the instaling packages portion where everytime I create a new terminal I recieve the following error:

```
& : File C:\Users\blain\hello\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ & c:/Users/blain/hello/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Ive been trying to get this to work for hours does anyone have any clue why its not working?

I installed python and installed this line in a command prompt
py -m pip install matplotlib

upon doing so I got this message
WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.11.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\blain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2

I dont really know what that means or how to address it

Comment: The first message is pretty clear.  Your machine is set to disable PowerShell scripts.  If you have admin access, you can change that:  https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/03/fix-for-powershell-script-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system.html